# CSS reverted on cache clearing

Tags: panels, chaos-tool-suite

I am using D7 with Panels and Panels Everywhere enabled and using the Versatile Theme.  I have changed the default versatile.css file to have the page-content div be 960px instead of 1020px.  All of the regions are % that are created using the Builder Flexible layout since the site is still under development.

Every time I clear the cache the css at -- /sites/default/files/ctools/css/ad57ff1546b4e3e493a0d16eb09e3ad9.css
reverts back to 1020px.

Seeing if anyone knows how to keep this from happening?

/* found out what I was doing wrong.  1020 was the default width that was still being used at the General page of Variant even though I changed the default setting in the Panels Mod.*/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found out what I was doing wrong. 1020 was the default width that was still being used at the General page of Variant even though I changed the default setting in the Panels Mod.